# /usr/local/bin/oh-my-posh error block use of Ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, wsl2

I installed oh-my-posh in Ubuntu-22.04 LTS. But something went wrong and when I tried to open Ubuntu-22.04 terminal on WSL I am getting errors related to /usr/local/bin/oh-my-posh. I cannot use the terminal at all anymore. I cannot even delete oh-my-posh file. Please help me with this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Usually the culprit in a case like this is going to be some issue with your `~/.bashrc` (or another related startup/config file).

There are several ways to recover from problematic startup files.  My first recommendation would be to start WSL from PowerShell using:

```
wsl ~ -e bash --noprofile --norc
```

This will simply start Bash, in your home directory, without attempting to run the Profile or RC files.  That *should* allow you to at least access the shell properly.

From there, edit your `~/.bashrc`.  Start at the bottom of the file and look for any lines that have been added regarding Oh My Posh.  Comment these out or remove them, then attempt to restart as usual.

If the above command still doesn't work, additional options include:

```
wsl -e nano /home/<your_username>/.bashrc # (or vi) to directly edit the file without running Bash
wsl ~ -u root # Launches as root instead of the default user
wsl ~ -e sh # Launches the dash shell instead of bash
wsl ~ -u root -e sh # Same as above, but as root
```